# Where do the matrices project vectors?

Tags: matrices

Consider the matrices
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 2 &3 \\ 1 & 3 & 5 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 \\  2 & -4 &2 \\ 3 & -6 & 3 \end{pmatrix} and
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\  0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. Do each of them project onto a plane, line, point or all of 3-dimensional space?

I'm pretty sure the first matrix projects vectors into all of 3-dimensional space because it's the identity matrix, but I'm not sure about the other 3.

Comment: Do you know about the *rank* of a matrix? That's the key to answering your questions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that the third matrix maps any vector in $3$-dimensional space to a multiple of $(1,2,3)$

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, no

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks! Wait would that mean it would map to a line?

Comment: OK, then what you should do is find the discussion of rank in whatever learning materials you are using, or online.

Comment: Yes, @rksrcl, the third matrix has rank $1$

Comment: Rank has nothing to do with the OP.